# How correctly overcome problem with an infinity MAPE?

Tags: model-evaluation, metric, mape

Should I choose an other metric or is the way to handle this problem?

Comment: There are many problems with MAPE, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299712/what-are-the-shortcomings-of-the-mean-absolute-percentage-error-mape/299713#299713 or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/280464/is-mape-a-good-error-measurement-statistic-and-what-alternatives-are-there/280469#280469, why do you need MAPE?

Comment: Just for better interpretation. Forecasting demand problem

Comment: @DmytroFedoriuk but MAPE is actually harder to interpret, since it is asymmetric by design...